# SQLite DLL - Failed to load exception

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I'm building an application using VS2010, C#, .NET4 with a SQLIte database in a Windows application, I'm trying to reference System.Data.SQLite which i`ve installed using NuGet into my project. I am referencing methods within the SQLite namespace without any issues, but running the application gives me the below exception, can someone help please?

> $exception    {"Unable to initialise application : Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Data.SQLite.dll' or one of its dependencies. A
>   dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x8007045A)"}   System.Exception

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your project, to install SQLite, you need to possibly install the SQLIte for (Windows Phone / Windows Runtime) Visual Studio extension, and always manually add the reference of SQLite.dll to the project.

Comment: thanks for replying. but i have the DLL referenced as methods within it are acceptable to me, and im able to see it in my references

Comment: What kind of application is it? The process changes depending on the Project type.

Comment: .NET 4 Windows Application

Comment: Try removing the package you've added, and instead getting System.Data.SQLite with NuGet

Comment: thanks, but the original question states that it is from NuGet